# oracle retrieve recursion level in trigger

Tags: oracle, recursion, triggers

Hi i have an oracle 12 database with some triggers firing after update which can cause other triggers to fire. I would like to retrieve the current recursion level in the trigger to be able to act differently whether the trigger is handling the "root" modification or the furthermore modifications which are initiated by the first trigger.

One possibility would be to create a package with a variable to store the recursion level and increment/decrement it with before-/after-triggers, but i am afraid that this variable could become inaccurate because of an error and then stay "forever" on the wrong value. I would prefer to retrieve this information directly from the database.
Unfortunately, i was not able to find a solution (query, system variable, ...) to retrieve the current recursion level. Is this possible?

Comment: You should not implement business logic in triggers - use PL/SQL packages and procedures for such tasks.

Comment: Don't think it's possible. Your design may work with an insert on a global temporary table (is truncated on commit) and a rowcount on that table to check the recursion level. However, if I were you I would double check my design because it does not sound very robust.